# RabbitMQ-server problems on CentOS 6

Tags: rabbitmq, boot

i have problem with running rabbitmq-server on CentOS 6.

Im getting such message while trying to start rabbitmq-server:

```
starting networking                                                      ...BOOT ERROR: FAILED
Reason: {badmatch,
            {error,
                {shutdown,
                    {child,undefined,'rabbit_tcp_listener_sup_:::5672',
                        {tcp_listener_sup,start_link,
                            [{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                             5672,
                             [inet6,binary,
                              {packet,raw},
                              {reuseaddr,true},
                              {backlog,128},
                              {nodelay,true},
                              {exit_on_close,false}],
                             {rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_started,[amqp]},
                             {rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_stopped,[amqp]},
                             {rabbit_networking,start_client,[]},
                             "TCP Listener"]},
                        transient,infinity,supervisor,
                        [tcp_listener_sup]}}}}
Stacktrace: [{rabbit_networking,start_listener0,4},
             {rabbit_networking,'-start_listener/4-lc$^0/1-0-',4},
             {rabbit_networking,start_listener,4},
             {rabbit_networking,'-boot_tcp/0-lc$^0/1-0-',1},
             {rabbit_networking,boot_tcp,0},
             {rabbit_networking,boot,0},
             {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1},
             {rabbit,run_boot_step,1}]
Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}})
```

In **rabbitmq-env.conf** i have:

```
NODENAME=main
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/
```

Also in **rabbitmq.config** i have:

```
[
    {rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0", 5672}]}]}
].
```

Hmm? Does anyone know where is the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to change the IP (e.g. leaving it out)? 0.0.0.0 looks pretty strange. Try 127.0.0.1 or leave like the default value.

Comment: I were trying... same effect ;/